# Newtonsoft.JsonReaderException - Input string is not a valid number

Tags: c#, http, iis, json.net

I am making an http post request to an app service hosted in Azure using Postman.

However when trying to deserialize the object being sent I get the error

> "exceptionMessage": "Input string '----------------------------020872859577165253890409' is not a valid number. Path '', line 1, position 52.

Below is an image of the object being sent

[image]

Here is the code that is supposed to process the Post request

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(HttpRequestMessage req)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Reached api function");           

    string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent); //errors out here

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

EDIT:

I have altered the code to return the jsonContent object by doing

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(HttpRequestMessage req)
{
    string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, jsonContent);

}
```

and the response in postman is

```
    "----------------------------492273134681850811150096\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"id\"\r\n\r\n932\r\n----------------------------492273134681850811150096\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 

name=\"response\"\r\n\r\nThis is a test\r\n----------------------------492273134681850811150096\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 

name=\"activities\"\r\n\r\nFun and stuff, Other\r\n----------------------------492273134681850811150096\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 

name=\"contact\"\r\n\r\nyesman12@yahoo.com\r\n----------------------------492273134681850811150096--\r\n"
```

Comment: To help you, we will need an [mcve] -- at the minimum the `jsonContent` string.

Comment: The content is not a string, it's form data. Read it as such.

Comment: And since it's form data, it's not [JSON](http://www.json.org/) so Json.NET is behaving as expected.